# Can't run rails c in terminal because of "Pry failed to get user input using `Readline`."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, readline, rails-console, pry

I can't seem to run rails c in terminal.
It keeps giving me this error

```
    Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0.beta2)
[1] pry(main)> Error: Input/output error - /dev/null
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:198:in `readline'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:198:in `block in input_readline'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:115:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:115:in `interruptible_region'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:197:in `input_readline'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:183:in `block in read_line'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:129:in `handle_read_errors'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:170:in `read_line'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:98:in `read'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:68:in `block in repl'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `loop'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `repl'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `block in start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:61:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:61:in `__with_ownership'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:79:in `with_ownership'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:15:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:169:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `require'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `block in require'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `require'
/Users/Bito/Desktop/office/movie/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `load'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in load'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `load'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:180:in `block in serve'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `fork'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Bito/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/Bito/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
-e:1:in `<main>'
[1] pry(main)> Error: Input/output error - /dev/null
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:198:in `readline'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:198:in `block in input_readline'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:115:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:115:in `interruptible_region'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:197:in `input_readline'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:183:in `block in read_line'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:129:in `handle_read_errors'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:170:in `read_line'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:98:in `read'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:68:in `block in repl'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `loop'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `repl'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `block in start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:61:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:61:in `__with_ownership'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:79:in `with_ownership'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:15:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:169:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `require'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `block in require'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `require'
/Users/Bito/Desktop/office/movie/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `load'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in load'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `load'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:180:in `block in serve'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `fork'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Bito/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/Bito/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
-e:1:in `<main>'
[1] pry(main)> Error: Input/output error - /dev/null
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:198:in `readline'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:198:in `block in input_readline'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:115:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:115:in `interruptible_region'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:197:in `input_readline'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:183:in `block in read_line'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:129:in `handle_read_errors'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:170:in `read_line'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:98:in `read'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:68:in `block in repl'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `loop'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `repl'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `block in start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:61:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:61:in `__with_ownership'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:79:in `with_ownership'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:15:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:169:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `require'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `block in require'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `require'
/Users/Bito/Desktop/office/movie/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `load'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in load'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `load'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:180:in `block in serve'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `fork'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Bito/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/Bito/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
-e:1:in `<main>'
[1] pry(main)> Error: Input/output error - /dev/null
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:198:in `readline'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:198:in `block in input_readline'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:115:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:115:in `interruptible_region'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:197:in `input_readline'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:183:in `block in read_line'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:129:in `handle_read_errors'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:170:in `read_line'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:98:in `read'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:68:in `block in repl'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `loop'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `repl'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `block in start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:61:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:61:in `__with_ownership'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:79:in `with_ownership'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:15:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:169:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `require'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `block in require'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `require'
/Users/Bito/Desktop/office/movie/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `load'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in load'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `load'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:180:in `block in serve'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `fork'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Bito/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/Bito/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
-e:1:in `<main>'
[1] pry(main)> Error: Input/output error - /dev/null
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:198:in `readline'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:198:in `block in input_readline'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:115:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:115:in `interruptible_region'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:197:in `input_readline'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:183:in `block in read_line'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:129:in `handle_read_errors'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:170:in `read_line'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:98:in `read'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:68:in `block in repl'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `loop'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `repl'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `block in start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:61:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:61:in `__with_ownership'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:79:in `with_ownership'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/repl.rb:15:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:169:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `require'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `block in require'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:248:in `require'
/Users/Bito/Desktop/office/movie/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `load'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in load'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.beta2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `load'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:180:in `block in serve'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `fork'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
/Users/Bito/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Bito/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/Bito/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
-e:1:in `<main>'
FATAL: Pry failed to get user input using `Readline`.
To fix this you may be able to pass input and output file descriptors to pry directly. e.g.
  Pry.config.input = STDIN
  Pry.config.output = STDOUT
  binding.pry
```

I tried google it and the only result I found is to add gem "rb-readline", :require => false to GemFile, but it doesn't work for me.
Anyone ran into the same issue? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue before, it ended up being a problem with rvm and my path while running rails/bundler commands from a particular prompt.

Try `rvm list` and `rails -v` to make sure there are no errors/inconsistencies. Then `bundle install` and `rails console` should work fine. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I'd love to know if this helped you out, or if you resolved it another way.

Comment: I uninstalled ruby and install a new version to fix, but thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Glad it worked it, but that's one of the best reasons to use [rvm](http://rvm.io) (or rbenv), you can manage one or more versions of ruby and rails in such a way that its trivial to add and remove them--they're not flat installed to your os. Might be worth looking into. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my case, The "rails console" was running in another terminal. The issue was resolved as soon as I ended the other execution of the "rails console".

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue today. You can just `spring stop` and relaunch your command.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by cleaning my gems and reinstalling using **bundler**. I was troubleshooting for a long time until I tried that, and then it was fixed in about 2 minutes :)

I used these two commands (**make sure you're inside the directory with the issue so bundler has the proper context**):

```
bundle clean --force
bundle install
```